# Only third post opening in for loop

Tags: javascript, html

Here is some example code that displays posts on the document that are stored in an array:

```js
var posts = [{
    title: "Post One",
    text: "This is the first post."
  },
  {
    title: "Post Two",
    text: "This is the second post."
  },
  {
    title: "Post Three",
    text: "This is the third and final post."
  }
];

for (var i in posts) {
  var post = document.createElement("div");

  post.addEventListener("click", function() {
  post.classList.toggle("expanded");
  });

  var title = document.createElement("h2");
  title.innerText = posts[i].title;

  var text = document.createElement("p");
  text.innerText = posts[i].text;

  post.appendChild(title);
  post.appendChild(text);

  document.body.appendChild(post);
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.expanded {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
Click a post to expand it:
```

However, when I click any of the posts, it always opens the last one.

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the scope of `var`. Replace `var post = document.createElement("div");` with `let post = document.createElement("div");`

```js
var posts = [{
    title: "Post One",
    text: "This is the first post."
  },
  {
    title: "Post Two",
    text: "This is the second post."
  },
  {
    title: "Post Three",
    text: "This is the third and final post."
  }
];

for (var i in posts) {
  let post = document.createElement("div");
  post.addEventListener("click", function() {
    post.classList.toggle("expanded");
  });

  var title = document.createElement("h2");
  title.innerText = posts[i].title;

  var text = document.createElement("p");
  text.innerText = posts[i].text;

  post.appendChild(title);
  post.appendChild(text);

  document.body.appendChild(post);
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.expanded {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `post` to `this` in your event listener:

```js
var posts = [{
    title: "Post One",
    text: "This is the first post."
  },
  {
    title: "Post Two",
    text: "This is the second post."
  },
  {
    title: "Post Three",
    text: "This is the third and final post."
  }
];

for (var i in posts) {
  var post = document.createElement("div");

  post.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("expanded");
  });

  var title = document.createElement("h2");
  title.innerText = posts[i].title;

  var text = document.createElement("p");
  text.innerText = posts[i].text;

  post.appendChild(title);
  post.appendChild(text);

  document.body.appendChild(post);
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.expanded {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
Click a post to expand it:
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the click eventListener. You need to pass this reference instead of post :

```
post.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("expanded");
  });
```